# All images in bulma carousel are displayed

Tags: carousel, bulma

I'm using bulma-carousel to show a slides of three images, it display *all* three images as slider (side by side) and they can be change the active, but the "no active" images are displayed too.

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="post_images" class="carousel">
            <div class="item-1">
                <figure class="image is-16by9 has-ratio">
                    <img src="path/to/image"/>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="item-2">
                <figure class="image is-16by9 has-ratio">
                    <img src="path/to/image"/>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="item-3">
                <figure class="image is-16by9 has-ratio">
                    <img src="path/to/image"/>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script>
   bulmaCarousel.attach('#post_images', {
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      loop: true,
    });
</script>
```

I made this [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/christianmtr/pen/MNJoXe).

Answer (score 3):

Solved with:

```
.carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```